# Как по SSH запустить .sh cкрипт, чтобы его исполнение не останавливалось при разрыве соединения?

Tags: shell, ssh, bash, linux

Например, есть скрипт do.sh. Я подключаюсь к серверу по SSH и запускаю скрипт на выполнение:

```
~/do.sh
```

Проблема в том что если отключиться от сервера или произойдет разрыв соединения то выполнение скрипта остановится. Как сделать так чтобы скрипт исполнялся дальше если я отключась от сервера или происходит разрыв соединения?

Comment: Смотрите команды nohup и batch (это сильно разные инструменты)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. nohup do.sh &
2. screen и в нем уже ./do.sh

Answer (score 4):

Думаю будет полезным утилита [screen](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen). В некоторых дистрибутивах линукс она предустановлена. Тем не менее, разобраться в документации и поставить небольшую утилиту не составит проблем. Она позволяет "разделять процессы на несколько окон" в одном терминале. При отключении от сервера "окна" screen сохранятся (процессы не завершатся), и в них можно будет вернуться при следующем подключении.

[Неплохой гайд для старта.](http://boombick.org/blog/posts/22)

Из минусов можно отметить то, что работа со скриптами как с демонами усложнится, но это все равно возможно.

Comment: Ссылка на гайд не работает.

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете запустить скрипт в фоновом режиме просто поставив в конце символ **&**
Так же я использую более приятный аналог screen - **tmux**

Например. Зашёл на сервер

```
tmux
```

В открывшейся консоли запускаю выполнение скрипта

```
./script.sh
```

Далее жму последовательно ctrl+b d и отключаюсь от консоли tmux. При этом все открытые процессы и окна в нём продолжают выполняться. 
При повторном входе на сервер набираю

```
tmux attach
```

и попадаю в тот же сеанс и продолжаю работать

[Краткий курс работы с tmux](https://romantelychko.com/blog/1392/)