# Открыть cmd на сервере через ssh

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, ssh, vps

Есть у меня доступ к VPS серверу, он на Ubuntu 18.04, через PuTTY я имею доступ до командной строки (т.е. терминала), и могу там вызывать команды, есть команда, которая запускается и пока этот теминал открытый она выполняет свое, но как только я его закрываю (у себя на компьютере) действия этой команды прекращается, замечаю я это т.к. эта команда транслирует на ip сервера некие данные, пока терминал открытый я их вижу, уже после закрытия нет.

Comment: дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/166527/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/422366/178576) и т.д. и т.п.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решений масса, выбирайте основываясь на том, зачем и как запускаете нужный процесс.

---

**Вариант 1.**

Используйте команду `nohup <нужная вам команда>` – она позволяет выполнять другие команды после закрытия консоли, также сохраняет весь вывод в файл (по умолчанию `nohup.out` в текущей директории).

Простейший вариант. Удобно для разового запуска долгих процессов (например, большие вычисления), но в принципе можно использовать для бесконечно живущих процессов (например, серверы).

---

**Вариант 2.**

Используйте процессы-демоны, запускающие другие подобные процессы. Например, [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/installing.html) или [systemd](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/systemd). В случае "гибели" запущенного процесса он автоматически перезапускается. Также у этих систем есть масса разнообразных параметров.

Удобно для процессов, которые должны работать постоянно и перезапускаться, если падают (например, серверы).

---

**Вариант 3.**

Используйте процесс-демон [cron](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/cron), который предназначен для запуска регулярных задач. Время запуска указывается простым, но очень мощным способом, что позволяет строить даже сложные правила вида *"каждые 5 минут с 11 до 13 по вторникам и четвергам"*.

Удобно для разовых процессов, которые нужно регулярно запускать (например, ежедневные отчёты).