# Запуск jar файла на linux сервере

Tags: java, linux

Я написал маленький скрипт на java, необходимо запустить на сервере который работает на linux. Я создаю jar файл с помощью IntelliJ IDEA делаю это так (File | Project Structure | Artifacts,  artifact, jar --> From modules with dependencies Потом Build | Build artifacts) после через программу putty подключаюсь к серверу и запускаю jar файл, скрипт работает нормально пока окно в котором я запустил jar открыто, но после закрытия окна  программы putty, скрипт перестает работать,почему так может происходить ?  За ранние прошу прошения за такой странный вопрос я новичок в программировании.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/166527/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-ssh-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-sh-c%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7

Comment: И ещё дубликат: [Открыть cmd на сервере через ssh](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/985676/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-cmd-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-ssh?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: И ещё один: [Если ssh внезапно закрывается, как сохранить результаты работы на удалённом хосте?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/422366/%d0%95%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-ssh-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82).

Comment: Спасибо, надо было лучше искать, я просто не знал как правильно спросить в google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Как вариант, сделайте следующее:

1. Напишите `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/myapplication.service`
2. Вставьте следующий код, отредактировав его под вашу программу:

```
[Unit]
Description= # можете тут добавить описание программы, если нужно
After=syslog.target
After=network.target[Service]
User= # напишите какой пользователь может пользоваться данной функцией, к примеру root
Type=simple

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /path/to/file/myapplication.jar
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier= # Короткое название вашей программы, например 'myapplication'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

3. Закрываем `nano` командами `Ctrl+x` далее пишем `y` или `Y` и жмем Enter.
4. Пишем следующюю строку для запуска проекта:

```
sudo systemctl start myapplication
```

Для завершения проекта:

```
sudo systemctl start myapplication
```

Для перезагрузки файла (в случае остановки/ошибки/обновлении файла):

```
sudo systemctl restart myapplication
```

Для просмотра статуса запуска:

```
sudo systemctl status myapplication
```

Comment: Можно и без `.service` Systemctl умный, по контексту понимает.

Comment: @Oxyd в `P.S.` я об этом написал

Comment: Вы написали вроде. Я подтверждаю -- не вроде, а чуть-ли не в манах описано.